# Twitter cards - Images from facebook cdn

Tags: facebook, twitter, metadata, meta-tags

I'm trying to make Twitter cards to let my users share some stuff on Twitter.

Here are my meta tag :

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@tonightFrance">
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@nicolas_lebot">
<meta name="twitter:url" content="<?php echo $url; ?>">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="<?php echo $title; ?>">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="<?php echo $image; ?>">
<meta name="twitter:image:width" content="<?php echo $widthImg; ?>">
<meta name="twitter:image:height" content="<?php echo $heightImg; ?>">
```

my $image can be 2 differents things, the first one is the image link on facebook or the image on my own server.

The display of the image works well when the image is on my server, but it never shows up when it's on facebook !

Is there something i'm missing ? Or maybe it's impossible to let twitter access the cdn facebook ? (I'm a little bit lost here)

Thank you

Comment: you should never use images from a facebook cdn for this, they are not meant to exist forever.

Comment: I'm using the graph API to get them actually so i will just have to change when they change

Comment: It is possible that Facebook blocks requests that come from “bots,” and not normal browsers. For their own Open Graph implementation, they explicitly prevent you from using images on their CDN for `og:image`. The proper solution here is to use images stored elsewhere - either on your own server, or a CDN that does not limit access in any way.

Comment: God, that sucks a lot.
Anyway thank's a lot for your answer, seems legit.